# サーバ上の特定ディレクトリ以下の最新1ファイルをコピーするには?

Tags: shellscript, freebsd

安物のネットワークカメラを買いました。ftp経由で転送されてくるのですが、
設定範囲が少なくて、妙案を探しています。(dbpower c300e、アマゾンで賛否両論あり)

/2016-11-08/Capture/13_57_20_200.jpg
/2016-11-08/Capture/13_59_20_319.jpg
/2016-11-08/Capture/14_02_20_498.jpg

上述のような要領で転送されてくるのですが、httpdで公開したいので、以下のような、
いつでも同じパスでアクセスできるようにしたいです。サーバ側はfreebsd、
tcsh等でして、crontabも使えるものの、スクリプトの書き方が分かりません。

/cam1.jpg

findで最新日時のjpgを探し、mvで公開ディレクトリへ名前指定でコピーしたあと、
カメラから転送されて、無限に増え続けるファイルを片付けるため、
日付付きのディレクトリを一括削除といった流れになるかなと
思うのですが、camera.shのようなスクリプトにまとめる際、
中身はどんなものが良いでしょうか?

find /home/camera-user/ -type f -name "*.jpg" | xargs -J % mv ...

mv -f /home/camera-user/*

xargsでつなげて、freebsdでは、jオプションがあるのはわかったものの、
mvの書き方がはっきりしません。日付の新しいものをsortするには、
さらにパイプする必要がありそうです。ヒット順は、最後が最新ファイルに
なるので、最後1ファイルを移動するだけでも良いような・・・。

mv % /home/www/public_html/cam1.jpg

Comment: その後、mvしていたら、カメラの不調時、転送されないままの場合、古いファイルが出てくるので、cpに変更、headの場合、転送途中の画像となることもあり、tailに変更しました。

Answer (score 1):

ファイルの最終修正日時の新しい順に取得し head で先頭1行取得したものを xargs でmv

こんな感じでどうでしょうか？
(複数ディレクトリからの取得にしてみました)

freebsd

```
ls -1 -t /home/camera-user/*/Capture/*.jpg | head -n 1 | xargs -J % mv -f % /destdir/dest.jpg
```

linux

```
ls -1 -t /home/camera-user/*/Capture/*.jpg | head -n 1 | xargs -I {} mv {} /destdir/dest.jpg
```

linux(bash)の方しか動確してません

Comment: ありがとうございます。頭が追いつかず、質問しました。検証してみるつもりです。しかし、lsコマンドではだめで、毎日、新たに日付のディレクトリができるため、findコマンドを使わねばなりません。でも、十分ヒントが頂けました。また、報告します。

Comment: ls -1 -t /home/camera-user/*/Capture/*.jpg  とか出来ませんか？

Comment: 無事に完成しました。スクリプトよりも、カメラの設定が進まず、四苦八苦しました。rmコマンドを使うので、何度も確認した後、cronの設定を終えて、様子見をしております。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

最新日付のディレクトリに cd で移動して、Capture の下の最新ファイルをコピーすれば良いと思います。
Cシェル書けないので 以下は sh で書きました。freebsdがないので試してません。間違っていたらすみません。

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin
export PATH

# 最新の日付ディレクトリ
cd /
DIRNAME="`ls -1d ????-??-?? | sort | tail -1`"

# 最新ファイル
cd  $DIRNAME/Capture/
FILE="`ls -tr1 *.jpg | tail -1`"

# ファイルコピー
cp $FILE /path/to/www/cam1.jpg

# 日付ディレクトリを一括削除
cd /
rm -rf ./????-??-??
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。いろいろな方法があるのだと気付かされます。特に、lsコマンドのrオプションが勉強になりました。今回は、先に返事を頂いた方の方法を採用しました。お世話になりました。

Answer (score 0):

こんな感じかなぁ? 同一ファイルシステムでないと `mv` で発生するコピーが無駄かも。

```
#!/bin/sh

set -u

incoming_dir="/var/ftp/camera"
latest_file="/var/www/html/camera/latest.jpg"

export latest_file

find "$incoming_dir" \
  -type f \
  -name "*.jpg" \
  -exec sh -c '
    set -u
    for incoming_file in "$@"; do
      if [ "$incoming_file" -nt "$latest_file" ] || [ ! -f "$latest_file" ]; then
        mv -- "$incoming_file" "$latest_file"
      else
        rm -- "$incoming_file"
      fi
    done
    ' sh {} + \
;

find "$incoming_dir" -type d -empty -delete
```

テストしたい場合は `mv` と `rm` の前に `echo` でも追加してみてください。

Answer (score 0):

`mv`せずにApacheにURLのルーティングを任せてしまうのはどうですか？

ファイルが多くなると`find`はコストが高そうですし、
FTPにアップロードされるファイルパスは、幸い単純な比較だけで
最新のファイルを特定できそうなので、ディレクトリツリーを歩く小さなスクリプトとmod_rewriteとRewriteMapを利用します。

OSX El capitan で動作確認済み。perlスクリプトをApacheにサーブさせないようにするにはもう一手間ぐらい必要そうですが、隠すほどのものでもないかも。

これならcronを待たなくてもいいですし。

#### httpd.conf

```
RewriteMap latest "prg:/var/www/find_last_filepath.pl"
```

#### /var/www/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule "^latest.jpg$" "${latest:pict}" [R=302,L]
```

#### /var/www/pict/* (FTPで直接ここにアップロードさせる)

```
/var/www/pict/2016-11-08/Capture/13_57_20_200.jpg
/var/www/pict/2016-11-08/Capture/13_59_20_319.jpg
/var/www/pict/2016-11-08/Capture/14_02_20_498.jpg
```

#### /var/www/find_last_filepath.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use FindBin qw($RealBin);
use File::Spec::Functions qw(catfile canonpath);

sub find_last {
    my @path = @_;

    # @pathにあるファイルを読む
    my @ls = reverse sort { $a cmp $b } grep {/^[^.]/} do {
        my $path = catfile(@path);
        opendir my $dir, $path or die "$!: $path\n";
        readdir $dir;
    };

    # ファイルとディレクトリに分割
    my @files = grep { -f catfile(@path, $_) } @ls;
    my @dirs  = grep { -d catfile(@path, $_) } @ls;

    # もしファイルもディレクトリも無ければこのディレクトリを諦める
    return if @files == 0 && @dirs == 0;

    # ディレクトリだけなら順に探索
    unless (@files) {
        for my $dir (@dirs) {
            my @found = find_last(@path, $dir);
            return @found if @found;
        }

        # どのディレクトリにも見つからなければやっぱり諦める
        return;
    }

    # ファイルだけなら最後のファイルを返す
    unless (@dirs) {
        return (@path, $files[0]);
    }

    # ディレクトリ名がファイル名より後ならディレクトリを探索しつつ
    if (($files[0] cmp $dirs[0]) < 0) {
        my @found = find_last(@path, $dirs[0]);
        return @found if @found;
    }

    # ファイル名にフォールバック
    return (@path, $files[0]);
}


# STDINに探索の開始パスを与える。
local $| = 1;
chdir $RealBin;
while (<STDIN>) {
    chomp;
    open my $fh, '>', '/tmp/prglog';
    printf {$fh} "%s\n", $_;
    my @found = find_last($_);
    printf "%s\n", canonpath(catfile(@found)) if @found;
}

1;
```

Comment: また、新しいアイデアを頂きました。ありがとうございます。